# Как без shadow build использовать .mac в проектах?

Tags: qt, юнит-тесты

У меня  есть проект и в проекте есть unit tests и  клас наследуется от QObject и в конце я  делаю

```
 #include "UnitTest.moc"
```

И по соседству  с папкой  с проектом есть  папка - build-Tests-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug в  ней  и хранятся .mac  и многое  другое. И если удалить  эту паку, все  оно не видит макросы((  Я  нашел в настройках  shadow build,  галочку убрал и все  не видит макросы тоже. Поэтому у меня вопрос - кто сталкивался с  этим. как  обойти чтобы можно было  без этой папки норм работалось и все виделось? чтобы я  мог на  другом проекте  с гитхаба  загрузить и оно работала.  без этой папки. я  не  удмаю что эту папку нужно тоже   на гит хаб сохранаять. В VS этого не нужно было  делать,  а тут  я  не знаю  уже)))

Comment: А зачем тебе это? Укажи пожалуйста свою цель. Как  я  понял тебе не нравиться чисто эстетическое явление в виде дополнительной папки с файлами .mac ??

Comment: если ты не хочешь иметь папку Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debu то при создании проекта просто создавай без дебаг версии проект. Если не нравиться расположение то просто в настройках "инструменты"-> "Сборка и запуск" пропиши в шаблоне с чтобы создавала программу прямо в папке проекта. **И да папку не надо сохранять  на гит хабе**, её твой компилятор собрал, там лежит машинный код.

Comment: @timob256 та не через естетические соображения. Просто вчера  на  другом компе  запустил програму и все. 3 часов коту под хвост. Не видит .moc и все. что я  не  делал. и  клин и qmake ничего не помогло. только когда создал заново проект и  все перенес  помогло. посмотрел . а оно  папку создает. поэтому и вопрос  задал

Comment: Makefile и .pro файлы, когда переношу на другой компьютер проект, то всегда удаляю  эти файлы

Comment: @timob256 аналогично+ я  еще  удалиk папку с Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug и  незнал что нельзя. я просто qt сreator только 1 мес использую. На VS я все удалял и при кампиляции  на  другом  компе все  норм работало... Поэтому и мне стало интересно  нужно ли оставлять эту папку. кfк я понял нужно.  без нее не   будут работать .moc